# How to I make a field sortable in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have tried, for example:

```
{
  "sort": [
    {
      "retail_price": {
        "reverse": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

... to no avail. Do I need to map the field a special way in order to enable sorting on it?

Answer (score 2):

The field should satisfy two conditions: 1) it has to be indexed and 2) it shouldn't have more than one value per document or more than one token per field. If retail_price is indexed in your case and it still doesn't work for you, could you post a script that demonstrates the problem?